# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, fatal-error

When i run my application in my phone which has android version 4.2.2. it will work correctly, but when i run it again in other phone like 4.1.2, ice cream sandwich, only the splashscreen will work correctly. and after 5 seconds, the application already stop.

This is my Logcat Error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dtournavigation.android/dtournavigation.android.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dtournavigation.android.fragments.MainFragment.isGPSEnabled(MainFragment.java:2277)
    at dtournavigation.android.fragments.MainFragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu(MainFragment.java:2164)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performPrepareOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1574)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1980)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:475)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:471)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:817)
    at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2667)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:633)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:781)
    at dtournavigation.android.fragments.MainFragment.onCreate(MainFragment.java:325)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1455)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
    ... 11 more
```

This is my Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dtournavigation.android"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="2.0.1" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="13"
              android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />


    <!-- Android Maps API V2 -->
    <permission
         android:name="edu.usf.cutr.opentripplanner.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="edu.usf.cutr.opentripplanner.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following permission is not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but is recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name="dtournavigation.android.OTPApp"  
        android:icon="@drawable/dtour_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  
        <activity
            android:name="dtournavigation.android.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="dtournavigation.android.MainActivity" />

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="dtournavigation.android.SettingsActivity" 
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <service android:name="dtournavigation.android.NavigationService" />
          <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAoJe7kIY7m6EGyZ3cPt7JCiLDwh9DZ09w"/>
        <activity android:name="dtournavigation.android.passtype.PassType"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".GlobalApplication"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme"></activity>
        <activity android:name="dtournavigation.android.fragments.DirectionListFragments"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
             </activity>
      <activity android:name="dtournavigation.android.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoTitle">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="dtournavigation.android.SMS"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
             </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my MyActivity.java File

```
package dtournavigation.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.opentripplanner.v092snapshot.api.model.Itinerary;
import org.opentripplanner.v092snapshot.api.model.Leg;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import dtournavigation.android.R;
import dtournavigation.android.fragments.DirectionListFragment;
import dtournavigation.android.fragments.MainFragment;
import dtournavigation.android.listeners.DateCompleteListener;
import dtournavigation.android.listeners.OnFragmentListener;
import dtournavigation.android.model.OTPBundle;


public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnFragmentListener{

    private List<Leg> currentItinerary = new ArrayList<Leg>();

    private List<Itinerary> currentItineraryList = new ArrayList<Itinerary>();

    private int currentItineraryIndex = -1;

    private OTPBundle bundle = null;

    private MainFragment mainFragment;

    private String TAG = "OTP";

    private String currentRequestString="";

    private boolean isButtonStartLocation = false;
    DateCompleteListener dateCompleteCallback;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity);


    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(OTPApp.TAG_FRAGMENT_MAIN_FRAGMENT);//recuperar o tag adecuado e pillar ese fragment

        }

        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFragment, mainFragment, OTPApp.TAG_FRAGMENT_MAIN_FRAGMENT);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch(requestCode) {
        case OTPApp.SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE: 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                boolean shouldRefresh = data.getBooleanExtra(OTPApp.REFRESH_SERVER_RETURN_KEY, false);
                boolean changedSelectedCustomServer = data.getBooleanExtra(OTPApp.CHANGED_SELECTED_CUSTOM_SERVER_RETURN_KEY, false);
                boolean changedTileProvider = data.getBooleanExtra(OTPApp.CHANGED_MAP_TILE_PROVIDER_RETURN_KEY, false);

                //              Toast.makeText(this, "Should server list refresh? " + shouldRefresh, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(shouldRefresh){
                    mainFragment.setNeedToRunAutoDetect(true);
                    mainFragment.setNeedToUpdateServersList(true);
                }
                if(changedSelectedCustomServer){
                    mainFragment.updateSelectedServer();
                }
                if(changedTileProvider){
                    mainFragment.updateOverlay(null);
                }
                break;
            }
        case OTPApp.CHOOSE_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
//              Log.v(TAG, "CHOOSE CONTACT RESULT OK");

                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
                    mainFragment.setTextBoxLocation(address, isButtonStartLocation);
                    mainFragment.processAddress(isButtonStartLocation, address, false);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {        

        mainFragment = null;

        Log.d(TAG, "Released mainFragment with map in MyActivity.onDestroy()");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItinerariesLoaded(List<Itinerary> itineraries) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        currentItineraryList.clear();
        currentItineraryList.addAll(itineraries);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItinerarySelected(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(i >= currentItineraryList.size()) return;

        currentItineraryIndex = i;
        currentItinerary.clear();
        currentItinerary.addAll(currentItineraryList.get(i).legs);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Leg> getCurrentItinerary() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return currentItinerary;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwitchedToDirectionFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        Fragment directionFragment = new DirectionListFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.mainFragment, directionFragment);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public OTPBundle getOTPBundle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOTPBundle(OTPBundle b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.bundle = b;
        this.bundle.setCurrentItineraryIndex(currentItineraryIndex);
        this.bundle.setItineraryList(currentItineraryList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwitchedToMainFragment(Fragment f) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(f);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        fm.popBackStack();
        transaction.commit();

        mainFragment.showRouteOnMap(currentItinerary, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentRequestString(String url) {
        currentRequestString = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentRequestString() {
        return currentRequestString;
    }

    @Override
    public void zoomToLocation(LatLng location){
        mainFragment.zoomToLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Itinerary> getCurrentItineraryList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return currentItineraryList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentItineraryIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return currentItineraryIndex;
    }

    /**
     * @return the isButtonStartLocation
     */
    public boolean isButtonStartLocation() {
        return isButtonStartLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @param isButtonStartLocation the isButtonStartLocation to set
     */
    public void setButtonStartLocation(boolean isButtonStartLocation) {
        this.isButtonStartLocation = isButtonStartLocation;
    }


    public void setDateCompleteCallback(DateCompleteListener callback){
        this.dateCompleteCallback = callback;
    }

    public void onDateComplete(Date tripDate, boolean scheduleType) {
        dateCompleteCallback.onDateComplete(tripDate, scheduleType);
    }

}
```

Mainfragment.java File: for onCreateOptionsMenu.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu pMenu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(pMenu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, pMenu);
        mGPS = pMenu.getItem(0);

    }   

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu pMenu) {
        if (isGPSEnabled()) {
            mGPS.setTitle(R.string.disable_gps);
        } else {
            mGPS.setTitle(R.string.enable_gps);
        }
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(pMenu);
    }

    private Boolean isGPSEnabled() {
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

Somebody can help me about this problem? Thank You Guys.

Comment: Please post code of MainFragment. The crash is caused by the onPrepareOptionsMenu in MainFragment class

Comment: Hello sir @Premsuraj, i already update my post. i posted only the optionmenus codes. it because, i have many characters for my mainfragment java file. and stackoverflow body has limited characters only. . Thank you for immediate response sir

Comment: Can you post the code of isGPSEnabled also? You can remove the code for onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: Sir, update my post above. i have remove already the optionItemSelected.

Comment: Where do you declare `locationManager`?

Comment: i declare it on the top..
this is how i declare

 private static LocationManager locationManager;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your locationManager object is probably null try this

```
private Boolean isGPSEnabled() {
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
}
```

Comment: oops sorry, fixed the answer. Please check

Comment: Then where did you initialise the locationManager instance? because it's value is null when the function isGPSEnabled is called. You may have to initialise it in onCreate() or onCreateOptionsMenu()

Comment: sir. already fix it. i just added that code to private boolean isGPSEnabled(){} . thnak you so much for helping me in fixing this basic problem but, a little bit harder for me. hehehe More Power Sir. God Bless :)